# galsim galaxy simulation with (local wcs) PSF

Tags: galsim

I would like to use `Galsim` to simulate a set of **galaxies convolved by PSFs**.

The **galaxies are simple double sersic profiles** that I create using the `Sersic` class from galsim (and then Shear to introduce some ellipticity).

The **PSFs I'like to use are pixellised images computed from Zemax** or CodeV ray-tracing simulations. They have been computed on a grid corresponding to the detector surface. This surface is tilted wrt the chiefray so **these PSFs already include the WCS distorsion of the detector tilt**.

I would like to compute the PSF-convolved galaxies on the detector surface. A possible way would be :

- to load the psf

`psf = galsim.InterpolatedImage(galsim.Image(psf))`

- then convolve by the galaxy :

`gal = galsim.Convolve(psf, gal)`

- then draw on the detector surface (with the tilt in the local_wcs):

`gal_image = gal.drawImage(wcs=local_wcs)`

I think that I am doing a mistake with the PSF beeing affected twice by the disrtorsion (the original tilt in the Zemax PSF + the local_wcs of the drwImage method). Are my worries correct ?

Shall I apply the local_wcs distortion to the original unconvolved galaxy (by applying a shear corresponding to the local_wcs) and then convolve by the psf and draw it on a non distorted wcs ? Would this correctly take in account the fact that my PSF is already distorted by the detector tilt ?

Comment: Thanks very much Zenoo for the editing !!

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a possible solution and that would be to specify the local_wcs when loading the PSF :

```
psf = galsim.InterpolatedImage(galsim.Image(psf), wcs=local_wcs)
```

Would that we a correct fix ? 
Will galsim  notice that it only needs to distort the galaxy and convolve by the PSF (and not un-distort the PSF, convolve the galaxy by the PSF and distort  the convolved galaxy) ?